# How to make a theme unable to be used on a multisite network?

Tags: theme-development, multisite

I have run across a WordPress theme that the developers intentionally set to not be usable on a multisite network. The theme was installed on my single site and then when I configured it to be a multisite network and did the initial log out and log back in I got a message that the theme could not be used on multisite networks but only standard single sites.

I'm curious how I could achieve this on a theme I'm developing, to make it unable to be used on a multisite network?

Answer (score 1):

This is right from the codex page, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_multisite

```
<?php if ( is_multisite() ) { echo 'Multisite is enabled'; } ?>
```